# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null

Tags: jquery

I'm using Nokia API to develop a webapp, and I need to refresh the map. So I delete the divs that contain it.

HTML :

```
<div id="spltMain">
    <div></div>
    <div id="conteneur_carte">
        <div id="carte"></div>
        <div id="uidContainer"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery :

```
$('#carte').remove();
$('#uidContainer').remove();
$('#conteneur_carte').remove();
$('<div id="conteneur_carte"><div id="carte"></div><div id="uidContainer"></div></div>').append('#spltMain');

// Get the DOM node to which we will append the map
var mapCont = document.getElementById("conteneur_carte");
// Create a map inside the map container DOM node
var map = new nokia.maps.map.Display(mapCont, {
    // Initial center and zoom level of the map
    //center: [parseFloat(lngMoy), parseFloat(latMoy)],
    center: [27.508271, -11.755371],
    zoomLevel: 6,
    components:[
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Behavior(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ZoomBar(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.TypeSelector(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.Overview(),
        new nokia.maps.map.component.ScaleBar()
    ]
});
```

N.B : The first time I create the map, I can see it in my page. But when I delete the containers, and try to create it again, I get : 
`Uncaught Error: IllegalArgument` or `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of null`

By the way, I'm using the library jqueryWidgets to manage the view of the page and add new functionalities.

Comment: Change `append` to `appendTo`

Comment: Gosh, I feel dumb xD
Thank you !!